# How can i change image at run time ?

Tags: android, image, runtime

```
public void buttonClickHandler(View target)
    {
        Intent answer = new Intent();

        switch(target.getId()){

        case R.id.Button01:
        {

            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.full_dog);
        }
        }
    }
```

**Basically i got one main background and 12 buttons on click of button i just want to call another image on it as user clicks the button that image should come in middle. **

Comment: Your question is very brief . If its difficult to explain your problem. You can  post a screen-shot and explain what you want to do.

Comment: @Maouz Qazi,ask your question with more deatail..it's incomplete one.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this - apply setonclicklistener for all the 12 buttons & and change the image

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
 final ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv);
 View b = findViewById(R.id.button1);
 b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.p2);
    }
});
  }
}
```

What did you mean by ''That image should come in middle''. Do you want the image to be aligned?

Comment: yeah I need the image at middle of the screen!

Comment: you can align the ImageView center_horizontal android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal